# Decoding incorrectly encoded characters

Tags: .net, character-encoding, itunes

A long time ago I imported a CD of Chinese music into iTunes.  The song names on the CD must have been in an encoding other than Unicode because they appear in iTunes as a string of nonsensical characters.  For instance for one song I see the string '°†'. I'm now trying to fix the song names.  Its been so long that I can't remember any of the song names or even who the artist was.

I don't know what the actual encoding is but I'm making the assumption that iTunes is trying to display the song name in Unicode \u00B0\u2020 (little endian). So that would give me the original bytes 0xB0 0x00 0x20 0x20.  So the song name could be 1 or 2 Chinese characters long depending on the encoding.

The most common non-Unicode encoding for Chinese is GB5 or Big-5. So I used the Encoding class in .NET to convert the bytes from Big-5 to Unicode.  When I display the characters in a WPF TextBlock it appears as '?'s and empty blocks (garbage).  I then tried 10 other Chinese character encodings.  They all appear as garbage in the TextBlock.

From what I can tell the problem can be in a number of places.

1.) iTunes may have lost some bytes in the import.
2.) 0xB0 0x00 0x20 0x20 may not be the original bytes
3.) iTunes made the wrong decision about what the original encoding was and tried to convert that to Unicode
4.) I haven't tried the correct encoding yet

It could be that TextBlock doesn't know how to display those characters but it is pretty good with Unicode.  I've used it to display Chinese Unicode characters before.

Does anyone else know what might be going on here?  Is my thinking completely incorrect?  Is there a better way to go about this?

**Edit:**

It turns out that iTunes is not using Unicode.  On my machine it appears to be using an ANSI code page.  So I decoded the characters using Windows-1252 (what the Encoding class says my default code page is) and then re-encoded them as Big-5.  This partially works.

My example above didn't turn out to be anything but when I looked at some of the other song names.  I was able to get something sensible.  For instance, '±I’æ«OÄÖ”y' becomes '寂保齡'.  You may noticed that the 2nd and 5th characters are not Chinese. So it didn't work entirely - but read on.

I did the artist name which was '±i´f©f' and that gave me '張惠妹' who is an actual Taiwanese singer, AKA A-Mei.  So then I searched on Google for 張惠妹 保齡.  This gave the the full song name '寂寞保齡球' English: 'Lonely Bowling'.  What I don't understand is why this works for some characters and not others?  Any ideas? Could I be using the wrong ANSI code page perhaps?

Comment: You can rule 4. in or out yourself by populating a TextBlock with a valid Chinese character.

Comment: `So that would give me the original bytes`.  No, that gives you the bytes that iTunes generated from the original bytes.  You already know they are wrong.

Comment: If iTunes didn't just copy the bytes over it must have made the wrong decision about what the original encoding was and tried to convert that to Unicode.  So Hans could be right that these aren't the original bytes.  In that case, I could try converting from unicode into each of the other encodings.  And then try to convert each of those from each of the 11 Chinese encodings into Unicode.  That only creates 121 possibilities.  I can look through each of them for something that makes sense.  Is this a good strategy?

Comment: Do you have an image or something of what the result should look like? That could simplify things a lot.

Comment: Try encoding the strings as big-endian UTF-16 and decoding as little-endian UTF-16: `Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("°†"))`. That's a wild guess, but `°†` is a pretty small sample and I can't read Chinese. It'd be easier if you could say what the expected string was.

Comment: It has been so long since I imported these songs I can't remember what the names were or even the artist name.  I don't think I even have the CD anymore.  I made some head way.  See the edit.